# Q: Remove materials using same image? (Python?)

Tags: python, texturing, materials

I've ripped a model from within an emulator. It creates an .OBJ that has hundreds of materials using the same image with different names
**[Material1(image1.png.001, image1.png.002); Material2(image1.png.001, image.png.004);Material3(image2.png.002);]** etc...

Is there a way I can clean all that up without having to manually go through and reassign textures for every face, in blender?

Comment: Sounds like a short python script may be needed.

Comment: This is some old code; but, If you understand 'C' at all; it may be useful for you.
https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=28239

Comment: so you are dealing with .obj file ?

Comment: either way would be fine, I've tried to create a fix in c++ for the obj, but can't quite get it to work.

Comment: Please share the .blend, you don't need to pack the images, just one :)

Comment: [Kill House C](http://fluffybuttgayming.ga/gameserver/killhouse_c.blend)